# How to position text in google sheets dialog box?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

In the dialog box that I have created for my google sheet, the text appears above the user input box. I want the text to appear, besides the user input box. Attached are the HTML and what the dialog box currently looks like. Would this be done through CSS or a different way?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table>
        <h5>LA/LB</h5>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alertLocation">
        </div>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Image of the current dialog box]

Comment: Remove the text from the header and use CSS to control text size`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="alertLocation">LA/LB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alertLocation" /><label for="alertLocation">LA/LB</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[label](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)